# suggestion on table relationship

Tags: mysql

I have to keep this data in MySql, and i am not sure (as SQL/databse is not my field) how to organise this into one or many tables? right now I would represent my info as follows:

```
device_name|HW_version|SW_version|IP_addr_pvt|IP_addr_pub|data_specific_to_device|associated_service   |associated_device
dev_x      | 1234     |1234      |1.2.3.4    |9.8.7.6    |data_specific_to_x     |SVC_A,SVC_B,SVC_C... |dev_y,dev_z,dev_n,dev_m...
dev_y      | 2348     |7734      |10.2.3.4   |99.8.7.6   |data_specific_to_y.....|SVC_B,SVC_X...       |dev_x,dev_m...
dev_z      | 3934     |5634      |11.2.3.4   |79.8.7.6   |data_specific_to_z.....|SVC_M                |dev_n,dev_m...
...
```

pl advice. what would be the best design? data_specific_to_device could be more than one column, as i get to explore the data a bit more.

and do i really need a device_id field? which any SQL table normally has.

I would like to add that data rarely(almost never) changes, and adds are also once twos a month.

ty.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple tables.

"associated_service" will be another table like this:

```
device_id service
```

In similar ways, "associated_device" will be a table:

```
device_id associated_device
```

Each of these can have multiple rows for one device_id

Does "data_specific_to_device" have different columns for different device types? In this case, you might want to have separate table for each device type, again indexed by the device_id of the device to get to the correct column.

EDIT: if your device names are unique, and you don't want to change them, you could use them as the device_id. You just need something suitable to look up the device across tables.

Comment: what benefit do i get by maintaining info in various tables. what shortcoming do you see with above plan(table structure)? kindly educate. ty.